# "assertion failed" warnings

Tags: ios, emulation, nativescript

I'm getting the following warnings/errors every time I run my ios emulator. At the moment the app is very simple, just a tutorial app. This is what I see in the console:

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

Project successfully built.
Using  /Users/wittner/Projects/nativescript/sample-Groceries/platforms/ios/build/emulator/sampleGroceries.app
Starting iOS Simulator
Apr 26 20:35:11 MacBook-Pro backboardd[5804]: SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: sampleGroceries[6014]
Apr 26 20:35:11 MacBook-Pro backboardd[5804]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, task->pid_self=-1
Apr 26 20:35:11 MacBook-Pro backboardd[5804]: SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: sampleGroceries[6014]
Apr 26 20:35:11 MacBook-Pro backboardd[5804]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, task->pid_self=-1
Apr 26 20:35:11 MacBook-Pro backboardd[5804]: SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: sampleGroceries[6014]
Apr 26 20:35:11 MacBook-Pro backboardd[5804]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, task->pid_self=-1
Apr 26 20:35:11 MacBook-Pro backboardd[5804]: SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: sampleGroceries[6014]
Apr 26 20:35:11 MacBook-Pro backboardd[5804]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, task->pid_self=-1
Apr 26 20:35:11 MacBook-Pro backboardd[5804]: SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: sampleGroceries[6014]
Apr 26 20:35:11 MacBook-Pro sampleGroceries[6014]: assertion failed: 15D21 13E230: libxpc.dylib + 71506 [6F98A9DA-B46E-3A2B-88D4-92F1EC77477F]: 0x7d
Apr 26 20:35:11 MacBook-Pro sampleGroceries[6014]: CONSOLE LOG file:///app/views/login/login.js:2:13: hello
```

the app is running fine and you can see my console.log() results at the end. I had some warnings during installation about cocoapods also but as I say, everything is, or seems to be running fine. Should I be worried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The libxpc.dylib is a normal assertion.  In fact it occurs with many of the different tool chains.

The Backboardd warnings are normal also on iOS.